# Abrir PDF em java em outra máquina

Tags: java, pdf

Fiz uma função que consigo abrir um PDF, porém essa função só está funcionando em minha maquina local. Quando eu executo o .jar gerado em outra máquina, é emitido um erro de que o arquivo PDFnão existe.

O trecho que executa tal função:

```
 try { 

   java.awt.Desktop desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();           
   desktop.open(new File("/manual.pdf")); 

} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(JFrameInicio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

O arquivo PDF está na seguinte localidade:
**\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Reitoria\src\reitoria**

Para criar o JAR, eu utilizo o método *package for store* que em meu pensamento, cria um jar com todos os arquivos necessários.

Creio que o PDF esteja sendo incluso no jar final pois sem colocar o PDF na pasta src, o jar fica com tamanho final de 3 MB, meu pdf também tem 3MB. Quando crio o jar com o arquivo PDF na pasta src, o .jar final fica com tamanho de 6 MB (creio que seja o jar + o arquivo PDF)

Comment: Coloque o erro da stack por favor. Pode ser questão de diretorio.

Comment: Java.lang.illegalArgumentException: The file \manual.pdf doesn't exist

Mas se o erro fosse no diretório, nao era para não funcionar mesmo em minha maquina local? (tanto executando pela propria IDE quanto pelo jar

Comment: Você tem que criar um arquivo temporario do PDF em disco, e fazer a leitura do arquivo para este arquivo. A ide roda seu problema descomprimido, por isso funciona, ja executando via `jar`, o pdf está dentro do pacote e não existe externo a ele. Veja isso aqui, pode ajudar. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28808187/5524514

Comment: vou olhar

muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Use um caminho que sempre validará em qualquer máquina como por exemplo "C:/" ou use caminhos relativos como a pasta de usuário `System.getProperty("user.home")` ou o caminho da classe/jar com `System.getProperty("user.dir")`.

Certifique-se de que o PDF está no caminho indicado.

Answer (score 0):

Quando criar o objeto File utilize como argumento **"./reitoria/manual.pdf"** visto que no NetBeans o que seria o diretório atual na linha de comandos é a pasta src.

Assim, o seu pedaço de código ficaria:

```
try { 

   java.awt.Desktop desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();           
   desktop.open(new File("./reitoria/manual.pdf")); 

} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(JFrameInicio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```